# Using sphinx autodoc for a fabfile

Tags: python, python-sphinx, fabric, autodoc

Is it possible to use Sphinx autodoc to generate documentation for my fabfile, from the function docstrings?

E.g. for a fabfile containing a `setup_development` task i've tried:

```
.. automodule::fabfile
   :members:
   .. autofunction:: setup_development
```

But nothing is generated.

fabfile snippet:

```
@task
def setup_development(remote='origin', branch='development'):
    """Setup your development environment.

    * Checkout development branch & pull updates from remote
    * Install required python packages
    * Symlink development settings
    * Sync and migrate database
    * Build HTML Documentation and open in web browser

    Args:
        remote: Name of remote git repository. Default: 'origin'.
        branch: Name of your development branch. Default: 'development'.
    """
    <code>
```

Comment: One problem is the missing space between `.. automodule::` and `fabfile`. And if you want to use `..autofunction::` (I don't think you need it), it should be preceded by a blank line.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Looks like ``:members:`` does not pick up wrapped functions (as per answer given by shahjapan), so I can either use ``wraps`` or use ``.. autofunction::`` which works with the ``@task`` decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce full documentation with preserved function signature by using the `decorator_apply` recipe [found in the documentation](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#dealing-with-third-party-decorators) for the [`decorator`](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html) module.

```
""" myfabfile.py """

from fabric.api import task as origtask
from decorator import FunctionMaker

def decorator_apply(dec, func):
    return FunctionMaker.create(
        func, 'return decorated(%(signature)s)',
        dict(decorated=dec(func)), __wrapped__=func)

def task(func):
    return decorator_apply(origtask, func)

@task
def setup_development(remote='origin', branch='development'):
    """Setup your development environment.

    * Checkout development branch & pull updates from remote
    * Install required python packages
    * Symlink development settings
    * Sync and migrate database
    * Build HTML Documentation and open in web browser

    :param remote: Name of remote git repository.
    :param branch: Name of your development branch.
    """
    pass
```

This is the simple ReST source that I used:

```
.. automodule:: myfabfile
   :members:
```

Some comments:

The answer submitted by shahjapan explains how to preserve the docstring in the general case, but it does not address the fact that the `@task` decorator is defined in an external library.

Anyway, it turns out that the docstring is preserved automatically for functions decorated with `@task`. The following is in the `__init__` method of Fabric's `tasks.WrappedCallableTask` class:

```
if hasattr(callable, '__doc__'):
    self.__doc__ = callable.__doc__
```

So that already works as it is (an explicit `.. autofunction::` is needed). To ensure that the function signature is preserved as well, the `decorator` module can be used as shown above.

---

**Update**

The use of the `decorator` module breaks things in the workings of Fabric (see comment). So that may not be feasible after all. As an alternative I suggest the following modified reST markup:

```
.. automodule:: myfabfile2
   :members: 

   .. autofunction:: setup_development(remote='origin', branch='development')
```

That is, you'll have to include the full function signature. This is also what is suggested in the Sphinx documentation (see ["This is useful if the signature from the method is hidden by a decorator.")](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule).

Comment: This works for autodoc, but using this method fabric no longer recognises its decorated tasks ``fab --list`` lists all functions (this is the fallback behaviour for backwards compatibility), in which case it would be easier to just omit ``@task`` completely. It also prevents imported tasks being found in other files when using ``fabfile`` as a module.

Comment: I guess the only way then is to duplicate the function names and signatures in both files. A bit of a pain, but thanks for investigating.

Comment: As we haven't really found a way to automatically generate docs for a fabfile, I've created an issue for Fabric over at github: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/569

Comment: Matt, in the issue report, you label both workarounds as "unsuccessful". But I'd say that manually specifying the function signature in the .rst file is a reasonable compromise. Yes, it is a bit of a pain that violates the "don't repeat yourself" principle. But both the Sphinx documentation that I referred to and the comment from the Fabric maintainer indicate that there is no better solution (for now at least). @task turns out to be especially complicated since it "involves a wrapped/delegate class and not just a nested or decorated function object".

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I'll have to rely on remembering to update the sphinx signatures whenever I add/modify a task. At least the documentation is still generated this way, and it's a lot better than what I had at the beginning of this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you! It was fun investigating this issue (and I learned a thing or two along the way).

Answer (score 3):

Its because you've applied decorator on your function `setup_development`

you need to update your `task` function with `functools.wraps` as below,

```
from functools import wraps

def task(calling_func):
    @wraps(calling_func)
    def wrapper_func(self, *args, **kw):
        return calling_func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper_func
```

If you document decorated functions or methods, keep in mind that autodoc retrieves its docstrings by importing the module and inspecting the `__doc__` attribute of the given function or method.

That means that if a decorator replaces the decorated function with another, it must copy the original `__doc__` to the new function.
From `Python 2.5`, `functools.wraps()` can be used to create well-behaved decorating functions.

References:

- [Python Sphinx autodoc and decorated members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687046/python-sphinx-autodoc-and-decorated-members)
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoexception

Comment: I can't for the life of me get this to work with the existing ``fabric.api.task`` decorator. Any change you could provide the specific code to decorate this existing decorator to pass-through ``__doc__``? Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Austin: So `autofunction` doesn't work with `@task` after all?

Comment: @mzjn autofunction half-works, the docstring information is generated, but the function args/kwargs are missing.

Comment: @shahjapan, can you explain why your decorator function looks the way it does? What is `calling_wrapper`? Where does `perm_context` come from?

Comment: @shahjapan, I still feel there's something missing. You say to Matt: "you need to update your `task` function with `functools.wraps` as below". How exactly is that supposed to be done? The original `task` function comes from the [Fabric library](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/usage/tasks.html#the-task-decorator).