# Getting sphinx to display function parameters when wrapped with decorator

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using **sphinx** to document a project and am having problems with functions wrapped in decorators. I have seen similar questions asked but no solution seems to fit my problem

I have hundreds of functions all wrapped in a custom decorator that itself can accept parameters

```
from functools import wraps

def CustomFunctionDecorator(id, name):
    """Custom decorator"""
    def outer(f):

        @wraps(f)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            ...do stuff....
            f(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return outer
```

My function will then look like this

```
@CustomFunctionDecorator(123, 'Test')
def TestFunction(a, b, c=None):
    """Test Documentation"""
    ..do something....
```

Now when i use sphinx and autodoc to generate my documentation, all of my functions wrapped in the CustomFunctionDecorator hide the actual arguments of the function in the sphinx documentation and appear like this

```
TestFunction(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Test Documentation*

The documentation works, but the function parameters don't....

Any ideas? hope i made myself clear

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448445/3001761):

> `functools.wraps` only preserves `__name__`, `__doc__`, and `__module__`. To preserve the signature as well take a look at Michele Simionato's [Decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator).

It's a workaround rather than a fix, but per [the documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) (emphasis mine):

> It’s possible to override the signature for explicitly documented
>   callable objects (functions, methods, classes) with the regular syntax
>   that will override the signature gained from introspection:
>
> ```
> .. autoclass:: Noodle(type)
>
>    .. automethod:: eat(persona)
> ```
>
> This is useful if the signature from the method is **hidden by a
>   decorator.**
>
> *New in version 0.4.*

Obviously that won't be fun for *"hundreds of functions"*...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont quite understand the automethod syntax from the example. what is eat and what is persona in terms of code?

Comment: `eat` is the method name, `persona` is a parameter name.

Comment: ok so that basically would mean i need to add that for each of my functions wrapped in my decorator that sphinx hides

Comment: That is one option, yes.