# Preserve default arguments of wrapped/decorated Python function in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, decorator, python-sphinx, python-decorators

How can I replace `*args` and `**kwargs` with the real signature in the documentation of decorated functions?

Let's say I have the following decorator and decorated function:

```
import functools

def mywrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Wrapping Ho!')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func

@mywrapper
def myfunc(foo=42, bar=43):
    """Obscure Addition

    :param foo: bar!
    :param bar: bla bla
    :return: foo + bar

    """
    return foo + bar
```

Accordingly, calling `print(myfunc(3, 4))` gives us:

```
Wrapping Ho!
7
```

So far so good. I also want my library containing `myfunc` properly documented with Sphinx.
However, if I include my function in my sphinx html page via:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members: myfunc
```

It will actually show up as:

### myfunc(*args, **kwargs)

Obscure Addition

- **Parameters:**

  - **foo**: bar!
  - **bar**: bla bla
- **Returns:**
   foo + bar

How can I get rid of the generic `myfunc(*args, **kwargs)` in the title? This should be replaced by **myfunc(foo=42, bar=43)**. How can I change sphinx or my decorator `mywrapper` such that the default keyword arguments are preserved in the documentation?

**EDIT**:

As pointed out this question has been asked before, but the answers are not so helpful.

However, I had an idea and wonder if this is possible. Does Sphinx set some environment variable that tells my module that it is actually imported by Sphinx? If so, I could simply monkey-patch my own wrappers. If my module is imported by Sphinx my wrappers return the original functions instead of wrapping them. Thus, the signature is preserved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Sphinx autodoc and decorated members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687046/python-sphinx-autodoc-and-decorated-members)

Comment: Sorry did not find the question. Yes it is the exact same one. But the answers are not very helpful I am afraid. I don't want to tediously manually add all decorated functions to my sphinx document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a monkey-patch for `functools.wraps`.
Accordingly, I simply added this to the `conf.py` script in my project documentation's sphinx `source` folder:

```
# Monkey-patch functools.wraps
import functools

def no_op_wraps(func):
    """Replaces functools.wraps in order to undo wrapping.

    Can be used to preserve the decorated function's signature
    in the documentation generated by Sphinx.

    """
    def wrapper(decorator):
        return func
    return wrapper

functools.wraps = no_op_wraps
```

Hence, when building the html page via `make html`, `functools.wraps` is replaced with this decorator `no_op_wraps` that does absolutely nothing but simply return the original function.

Comment: This is... frightening.  I sure hope Sphinx doesn't call `functools.wraps()` anywhere in its own codebase.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in `conf.py`, though it doe (rather uselessly) if I put it right before my definitions of wrappers. Is there a special place in `conf.py` that this needs to be?

Comment: I put it at the end of ``conf.py``. But I guess you have to be careful to include it before any other module is imported that makes use of ``functools.wraps`` in terms of ``from functools import wraps``.

Answer (score 2):

You ordinarily can't.
That is because the variable names used as parameters in the wrapped function are not even present on the wrapped function  - so Sphinx do not know about them.

That is a known complicated issue in Python - so much that recent versions - including not only Python 3, but also Python 2.7 included a `__wrapped__` attribute on class decorated that make the proper use from `functools.wraps` -
that way, upon inspecting the decorated function one is able to know about the actual wrrapped function by looking at `__wrapped__`. Unfortunatelly, Sphinxs ignores the `__wrapped__`, and show the info on the wrapper function instead.

SO, one thing to do is certainly to report this as a bug to the Sphinx project itself - it should take `__wrapped__` in account.

A meantime workaround for that would be to change the wrapper function to actually include more information about the wrapped - like its signature - 
so you could write another function to be called in place of "functools.wraps"  for your project, which does just that: pre-pend the 
function signature to its docstring, if any. 
Unfortunatelly, retrieving the function signatures in Python older than 3.3 is tricky - (for 3.3 and newer, check https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect-signature-object ) - but anyway, for a naive form, you could write another version of "wraps" along:

```
def wraps(original_func):
   wrap_decorator = functools.wraps(original_func)
   def re_wrapper(func):
       wrapper = wrap_decorator(func)
       poorman_sig = original_func.__code__.co_varnames[
                         :original_func.__code__.co_argcount]
       wrapper.__doc__ = "{} ({})\n\n{}".format (
            original_func.__name__, ", ".join(poorman_sig),
            wrapper.__doc__) 
       return wrapper
   return re_wrapper
```

And use that instead of "functools.wraps". It would at least add a line with the parameter names, (but not th e defalt values) as first line in the docs.

---Hmm..maybe it would be easier just to patch Sphinx to use `__wrapped__` before getting this done right.

Comment: I guess I could extract the function's default arguements using ``inspect``  and ``inspect.getargspec(myfunc)``?! But still pre-pending this information to the docs would not get rid of the wrong title.

Comment: I created a new github issue for this problem: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1711