# Sphinx docs do not list arguments of decorated functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx, python-decorators

When I apply my own decorator (the details are not important, but see below) or other decorators such as `cached`, from cachetools, my Sphinx-generated docs do not show argument names in their signatures.

For example, the documentation for

```
@cached()
def some_func(argA, argB=None):
    ...

@require_unicode('third')
def another_func(first, second=None, third=None):
...
```

will read, generically

> some_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> another_func(*args, **kwargs)

rather than, informatively, as

> some_func(argA, argB=None)
>
> another_func(first, second=None, third=None)

How can I remedy this so that my argument names appear in my Sphinx documentation? I understand that this is a known issue, and, since I know the names of the decorators I use, I've thought of just making them into no-ops, in my `conf.py` but can't figure out how do to that.

For example, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371786/656912) seems promising, but I'm at a loss how to get it working. I can put it before the my definition above, but can't see how to get it working for `cached`.

---

My decorator, for reference. Note that at least this generates docs (which it wouldn't if I didn't use `wraps`):

```
from functools import wraps

def require_unicode(*given_arg_names):
    def check_types(_func_):
        @wraps(_func_)
        def modified(*args, **kwargs):
            arg_names = list(_func_.func_code.co_varnames[:_func_.func_code.co_argcount])
            if len(given_arg_names) == 0:
                raise TypeError('No arguments provided to require_unicode decorator.')
                #unicode_arg_names = arg_names
            else:
                unicode_arg_names = given_arg_names
            for unicode_arg_name in unicode_arg_names:
                try:
                    arg_index = arg_names.index(unicode_arg_name)
                    if len(args) > arg_index:
                        arg = args[arg_index]
                    elif unicode_arg_name in kwargs:
                        arg = kwargs[unicode_arg_name]
                    else:
                    if not isinstance(arg, unicode):
                        raise TypeError("Parameter '{}' should be Unicode".format(unicode_arg_name))
                except ValueError:
                    raise NameError(unicode_arg_name)
            return _func_(*args, **kwargs)
        return modified
    return check_types
```

Comment: I don't think you can fix that, because the signature *is* now the generic decorator signature. Are you not documenting the parameters too?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28371786/656912) seems promising, but I'm at a loss how to get it working. I can put it before the my definition above. but can't see how to get it working for `cached`.

Comment: You'll have to see if `cached` is using `wraps` and monkey-patch it there, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's generic only if I let things get that far. If I can intercept the decorators somehow, when documentation is being generated, I can fix the problem (see previous comment).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That's the question. Where's "there"?

Comment: Then could you edit the question, such that that's what it says?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code for `cached`](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/blob/master/cachetools/__init__.py#L34), it doesn't use `functools.wraps`, so your current monkey patching won't succeed there. It uses either `functools.update_wrapper` or its own version, aliased to `_update_wrapper`, so you'll need to patch out that. If you're using any other libraries with their own ways of implementing wrapping, you'll need to investigate each one accordingly.

Comment: Yes, just saw the same thing. Can you help with (a) what the patch to `cached` should look like and (b) where to place my patch for it (so that it affects only document builds). I can get the patch for my decorator working by putting it before its definition (and conditionally executing with a flag I set in `conf.py`).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius why don't you do it as the linked question does, patching `wraps` out in `conf.py` so that you don't have to let that documentation implementation detail bleed into your actual code? `cachetools._update_wrapper` can then be patched trivially with e.g. `lambda wrapper, func: func` to no-op the wrapping. Or patch Sphinx to use `__wrapped__`, as the second answer suggests.

Comment: Actually, that part of the answer doesn't work. Putting the patch right before my definition works, but putting it in `conf.py` has no effect.

Comment: So where I need help is figuring out where it goes. Your suggestion to patch Sphinx to use `__wrapped__` may also work (it might even be better, though I have less idea how to pursue that!).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I think you need to spend more time doing research and working on this to narrow down exactly what your question is.