# Documenting jit-compiled PyTorch Class Method (Sphinx)

Tags: pytorch, python-sphinx, autodoc, torchscript

I am having a problem trying to document custom PyTorch models with Sphinx: methods that are jit-compiled show up without docstrings in the documentation. How do I fix this? I checkoed out [Python Sphinx autodoc and decorated members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687046/python-sphinx-autodoc-and-decorated-members) and [How to autodoc decorated methods with sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071961/how-to-autodoc-decorated-methods-with-sphinx) but the proposed solutions don't seem to work. When I try using `..automethod` I get

```
AttributeError: '_CachedForward' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Here's a MWE; at the moment I circumvent the problem by writing a `my_forward` and calling it in the `forward`.

```py
from torch import jit, Tensor


class DummyModel(jit.ScriptModule):
    """My dummy model"""

    def __init__(self, const: float):
        super(DummyModel, self).__init__()
        self.const = Tensor(const)

    @jit.script_method
    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        """This method does show as a :undoc-member: in the documentation"""
        return self.my_forward(x)

    def my_forward(self,  x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        """This method shows up as a :member: in the documentation"""
        return x + self.const
```

Comment: I know very little about PyTorch. Would it help to set `PYTORCH_JIT=0` when running Sphinx? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#disable-jit-for-debugging

Comment: @mzjn That indeed did the trick, thanks a lot! I would suggest you write it as a real answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `PYTORCH_JIT` environment variable to 0 when running Sphinx. This will disable script and tracing annotations (decorators).

See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#disable-jit-for-debugging.